# Fail mechanism for a unity rythm game

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

Hello i know this question might be a bad one but i have tried everything to my ability to acomplish this but i cant, so i have been making a rythm game and for the life of me i have made everything else other than the fail mechanism i just cant get it to work. i need to read the variable (MissedNotes) and make the code pause the time and show text saying (Too Many Notes Missed). I have made the place to insert the text in but i cant figure out how to do it at all. Im a begginer so any help is good, Thanks for helping me.

This is the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public AudioSource theMusic;
    public AudioSource beatSfx;

    public bool startPlaying;

    public BeatScroller theBS;

    public static GameManager instance;

    public int currentScore;
    public int scorePerNote = 2000;
    public int scorePerGoodNote = 2500;
    public int scorePerPerfectNote = 3000;

    public int currentMultiplier;
    public int multiplierTracker;
    public int[] multiplierThresholds;

    public Text scoreText;
    public Text multiText;

    public float totalNotes;
    public float NormalHits;
    public float GoodHits;
    public float PerfectHits;
    public float MissedHits;

    public GameObject resultsScreen;
    public Text percentHitText, normalsText, goodsText, perfectsText, missesText, rankText, finalScoreText;

    public GameObject FAILTEXT;



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        instance = this;
        scoreText.text = "Press Any Key to Continue";
        
        currentMultiplier = 1;
        totalNotes = ((FindObjectsOfType<NoteObject>().Length) - 168);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (!startPlaying)
        {
            if (Input.anyKeyDown)
            {
                scoreText.text = "0";
                startPlaying = true;
                theBS.hasStarted = true;
                theMusic.Play();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!theMusic.isPlaying && !resultsScreen.activeInHierarchy)
            {
                resultsScreen.SetActive(true);
                normalsText.text = "" + NormalHits;
                goodsText.text = "" + GoodHits;
                perfectsText.text = "" + PerfectHits;
                missesText.text = "" + MissedHits;

                float totalHits = NormalHits + GoodHits + PerfectHits;
                float percentHit = (totalHits / totalNotes) * 100f;
                float totalMiss = MissedHits;


                

                percentHitText.text = percentHit.ToString("F1") + "%";

                string rankVal = "F";

                if (percentHit >= 30)
                {
                    rankVal = "D";
                    if (currentScore >= 550000)
                    {
                        rankVal = "C";
                        if (currentScore >= 750000)
                        {
                            rankVal = "B";
                            if (currentScore >= 900000)
                            {
                                rankVal = "A";
                                if (currentScore >= 950000)
                                {
                                    rankVal = "S";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                rankText.text = rankVal;
                finalScoreText.text = currentScore.ToString();
            }
        }


     




    }







    public void NoteHit()
    {
        beatSfx.Play();
        multiplierTracker++;
        if ((currentMultiplier - 1) < multiplierThresholds.Length) 
        {
            multiplierTracker++;

            if (multiplierThresholds[currentMultiplier - 1] <= multiplierTracker)
            {
                multiplierTracker = 0;
                currentMultiplier++;
            }
        }

        scoreText.text = "" + currentScore;
        multiText.text = "Score x" + currentMultiplier;  
    }

    public void NormalHit()
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Normal Hit");
        currentScore += scorePerNote * currentMultiplier;
        NormalHits++;
        NoteHit();
    }

    public void GoodHit()
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Good Hit");
        currentScore += scorePerGoodNote * currentMultiplier;
        GoodHits++;
        NoteHit();
    }

    public void PerfectHit()
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Perfect Hit");
        currentScore += scorePerPerfectNote * currentMultiplier;
        PerfectHits++;
        NoteHit();
    }

    public void NoteMissed()
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("missed");
        MissedHits++;
        currentMultiplier = 1;
        multiplierTracker = 0;
        multiText.text = "Score x" + currentMultiplier;







    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing controlling time here so there's not really anything to do in this class to pause time. I'm also not seeing how the note hit functions are called.

It seems like there's some other class controlling the timing and note hit logic, and that's where you need to implement the logic to stop the game.

Once you've done that you can modify your NoteMissed method to trigger the game logic to stop when too many notes are missed.

Comment: i think im trying to do too many hard things as a begginer

Comment: It's how everyone learns. You start the project, charge headfirst into the weeds, realize how quickly everything gets unmanageable, daydream about how you'd do things differently, and eventually get so dissatisfied that you either gut and rewrite the code ("refactor") or you abandon the project and start something else. Then you try to take that other approach, charge headfirst into different weeds, and quickly realize how unmanageable that is. Senior developers know what a bad approach is, what a bad code smell is, etc., because they all did it that way once and know why it's terrible.

Comment: yeah, honestly this whole project im doing has mentally hit me really bad cause i cant figure anything but hey at least im learning kind of